# Appending to an object literal

Tags: javascript

I pass an object literal to a function like this:

```
pre( {model:'MUserTry'} );
```

I then wish to augment it, but I end up writing over it like this.

```
    pre : function( o_p ) {
        o_p = {
            result: '0',
            page  : {}
        };
```

model is now gone as o_p is completely new

What is the best way to append object properties.

Do you have to explicitly define them now.

```
o_p.result = 0;
o_p.page = {};
```

or is there a function that will allow me to write out the object literal and combine them?

kind of like this

```
object1.push (object2 );
```

Comment: If you want to combine them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the local variable o_p is redefined by the assigning:

```
function( o_p ) {
    // assign a new value to local variable o_p
    // object passed as an argument is untouched
    o_p = {
        result: '0',
        page  : {}
    };
}
```

You could merge your objects like this :

```
function( o_p ) {
    var mergee = {
        result: '0',
        page  : {}
    };
    for (var attrname in mergee) { o_p[attrname] = mergee[attrname]; }    
}
```

Alternatively, if you can use JQuery, you can just use the extend method:

```
function( o_p ) {
    var mergee = {
        result: '0',
        page  : {}
    };
    $.extend(o_p, mergee);
}
```

Comment: This question is also addressed more extensively [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

To add new object properties or methods, use the dot operator:

```
obj.dog = "woof";
```

This is also equivalent:

```
obj["dog"] = "woof";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add properties by assigning to them:

```
o_p.result = '0';
```

This won't create a new object and thus retain your `model` property.